# Show layout in Marionette.Application inside controller

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to structure my code with MVC flow within my application. I am trying to show created layouts in my marionette app instance within my marionette.controller as below..

1. Can anyone please tell me is it a proper way to show or change layouts within controller is proper way or not? And if not then what's the proper approach for that.

My Controller

```
define([ 'marionette', 'app', 'index_view' ], function( Marionette, App, IndexView ) {
console.log("Inside...ViewFlow Controller.");
var ViewFlow_Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    loadIndex : function() {
        console.log("Inside...Load Index Method.");
        App.main.show( new IndexView() );
    }
});
return new ViewFlow_Controller();
});
```

where my IndexView is like this

```
define(['app', 'helper', 'templates'],
function (App, Helper, templates){
console.log("Inside...Index View.");
App.Page_Index = (function(){
    var Page_Index = {};

    var _pageName = 'IndexPage';        
    var _pageLayout = Helper.newPageLayout({
        name:_pageName,
        panelView:      Helper.newPanelView(),
        headerView:     Helper.newHeaderView({name:_pageName, title:'Welcome to the Index Page'}),
        contentView:    Helper.newContentView({name:_pageName, template: templates.content_index}),
        footerView:     Helper.newFooterView({name:_pageName, title:'IndexPage Footer'})
    });

  return Page_Index;

})();

return App.Page_Index;
});
```

My helper returns me App_Layout instance.
But it's not working, it's giving me an error

```
Uncaught TypeError:object is not a function   viewflow_controller.js:12
```

Please help me out.

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/rachnakhokhar/VIBE_JRM_Framework.git) if you want to refer to the complete code or contribute.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on GitHub seems to contain only empty files (aside from the libraries), so I'm going to assume `Helper` returns a layout instance (which you seem to have indicated, saying it returned an `App_Layout` instance).

It looks like you're using layouts wrong. The way to use layouts is basically:

1. Create a layout instance with regions (e.g.) `panelRegion` and `contentRegion`
2. Create view instances that will be displayed in the layout (e.g.) `panelViewInstance` and `contentViewInstance`
3. Write a handler to show your views when the layout itself is shown.

The handler should look like this:

```
  myLayout.on("show", function(){
      myLayout.panelRegion.show(panelViewInstance);
      myLayout.contentRegionshow(contentViewInstance);
  });
```

Then, show that layout in one of your app's regions:

```
  MyApp.mainRegion.show(myLayout);
```

The documentation on layouts is here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md

You can learn more on using layouts and structuring your code in my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction).

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I am sorry for the code on Github..now i have commited my files..Please take a look..I have done things as stated by you above. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Solved issue with minor changes.